# What is the verb 'to be' for the phrase "The mechanics of the mind"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, verb-agreement, be

Should one use "the mechanics of the mind are" or "the mechanics of the mind is?

- The term "mechanics", used in this sense, seems to be an uncountable noun.

Comment: The trouble with this is conceptual. 'Mechanics' is to do with machinery. The mind is organic and spiritual. 'The mentality of the mind' is how I, personally express the concept. And then I have no trouble, for it is singular. 'The mentaltiy of the mind is ...'.

Comment: @NigelJ This expression infers a meaning of "how the mind works".

Comment: Countable or not, it’s a plural concept (like *inner workings*, or *underlying rules*, or …) so *are* is appropriate. Substitute *mechanisms* if that reads more comfortably for you.

Comment: @WillCrawford Could you put that in an answer? That helped me, thanks. I'll upvote it as well as mark it as the right answer when you do so.

Comment: I'll try to write up something a little better :o)

Comment: As it is, you need the singular here. However, it may help if you provide the broader context.

Comment: He really doesn't ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of *the mechanics* is something like

> *The sum of [the rules governing] the behaviour of the inner workings of*

which, as you say, isn’t exactly countable but it’s a plural concept — each internal behaviour is *a* mechanic. Other ways to say the same thing are, e.g., *inner workings* or *underlying rules*, or …

Depending a little on what you’re trying to articulate you may find substituting *mechanisms* makes it sound better (and doing so as a “thought exercise” might help make the plurality more obvious).

Other examples that might help are: *metabolism* (singular) versus *metabolic pathways* (plural); *skeleton* versus *bones*; *wood* versus *trees*.

The actual answer to your question is left as an exercise to the reader.

[There's another example: *exercises* versus *exercise régime*]